# How to force Chrome to keep tabs in memory?

Tags: google-chrome

When I am low on memory, Chrome discards tabs in the background. It reloads the page, when I try to switch to that tab.

I have important work on some of that tabs, and I would like to prevent Chrome to discard them. I do not care, if I run out of memory and have to use pagefiles. Those tabs need to be kept open. How is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `chrome://discards/`

Toggle "Auto Discardable" to X for the tabs you need to keep active.

Comment: This doesn't remember a website. One needs to do it everytime one wants a tab to be excluded, on each restart.

Comment: @HappyFace check out this extension: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/disable-automatic-tab-dis/dnhngfnfolbmhgealdpolmhimnoliiok

Comment: @HappyFace keep in mind that the flags set through `chrome://` are experimental stuff that google might change whenever they feel it appropriate.