# Can you keep a Chrome tab always active every time you go to a specific site?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

On another question here at superuser, it was asked: [How to force Chrome to keep tabs in memory?](https://superuser.com/questions/1632838/how-to-force-chrome-to-keep-tabs-in-memory)

Someone responded with:

Go to chrome://discards/

Toggle "Auto Discardable" to X for the tabs you need to keep active.

This works, but I have to do it every time I visit the site. Every time I go to the site, I then have to open a new tab, open the discards, and then toggle the "Auto Discardable" to X.

Is there a way to automatically toggle "Auto Discardable" to X every time I connect to the site?